# Using Spark Accumulators with Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

In my structured streaming job I am updating Spark Accumulators in the updateAcrossEvents method but they are always 0 when I try to print them in my StreamingListener. Here's the code:

```
.mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout())(
        updateAcrossEvents
      )
```

EDIT: Some more info to describe the problem in more detail...

The accumulators get incremented in 'updateAcrossEvents'. I've a StreamingListener which writes values of the accumulators in 'onQueryProgress' method but in this method the Accumulators are **ALWAYS ZERO!**

When I added log statements in the updateAcrossEvents, I could see that these accumulators are getting incremented as expected.

This only happens when I run in the 'Cluster' mode. In Local mode it works fine which implies that the Accumulators are not getting distributed correctly - or something like that!

Note: I've seen quite a few answers on the Web that tell me to perform an "Action". That's not a solution here. This is a 'Stateful Structured Streaming' job. Yes, I am also 'registering' them in SparkContext.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print it outside the transformation operation(map) before you call an action? If so it will be 0 as the spark is using lazy execution. The code inside your map operation will not be called until you call an action on the dataset.

```
df.map{ x => accum.add(x); x }.count
println(accum.value)
```

This would work.

Comment: This accumulator is passed to another class which extends from StreamingQueryListener. I am trying to print value in this Listener.

Comment: @DilTeam  did you find any solution for this ?